# Is a virtual encrypted disk stored in a file on a NAS allowing for concurrent R/W access?

Tags: encryption, nas

I'd like that all the data stored in a NAS is encrypted. The NAS is used for a) daily backups AND b) as a **shared** hard disk for users, allowing thus concurrent read/write access. All machines are Linux, so no need to take into account Windows (eg Samba).

I plan to build on this NAS a virtual encrypted disk using a loop device and cryptsetup. Some questions:

- Several users will mount this virtual drive and access in read/write, is this ok or could there be problems?
- Would the performance of this method by reasonable or are there faster approaches for shared encryption?

Comment: It's a fair enough question, but there is no single right answer. [This question isn't appropriate for this site.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: I reformulated the question, I hope it is ok now

Comment: The "virtual disk" is just a file, as far as the NAS cares. It should work just the same as non-encrypted disk.